# Passing Arguments to contructor

Tags: magento2, object-manager

I am having a situation where I need to instantiate a helper object from my custom module in list.phtml file.
For this I have two options either I need to overrride productlist.php and pass the helper class in constructor or use object manager.
And I am not satisfied from both of the options..
Can anyone suggest me how can I pass this argument in constructor and use it in my phtml file ?
I have read a lot about virtual types and type arguments in di.xml
Any help in doing this?

Comment: you can try this `$_helper = $this->helper('{your custom module Vendor}\{Custome module name}\Helper\{Class name which is in Helper folder}');`

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me
$this->helper() is available to use..
Can you also guide me if it is possible to use di.xml in this case?

Comment: If you want to access helper in PHTML file then `di.xml` file not require.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using `ViewModel`. The view model is injected into the block via layout XML.
You just add an additional XML argument to the Block class - either when creating the block using `<block>` or when referring to the block using `<referenceBlock>`.
You can go through following articles for more details :

- https://www.integer-net.com/view-models-in-magento-1-and-2/
- https://www.yireo.com/blog/1856-viewmodels-in-magento-2
- https://firegento.com/blog/2017/12/07/better-blocks-magento-2-php-view-models/

Comment: Perfect..
this is what I am looking for.
magento do offer us a lot of options the only thing is we don't know where and how to use them :P

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$_helper = $this->helper('{your custom module Vendor}\{Custome module name}\Helper\{Class name which is in Helper folder}');
```

Comment: Although this work but I was not looking for this..
Thanks anyway :)